# Android: mySQL, create table command

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, command-prompt

I'm trying to create a table and I've tried so many times to figure this out... for some reason it won't accept this.. it's saying something about the auto_increment

```
create table if not exists Assignments(
    id auto_increment primary key,
    class_name VARCHAR(30),
    assignment_name VARCHAR(30) not null,
    due_date VARCHAR(30) not null,
    notes VARCHAR(30));
```

whats the problem?

EDIT: i am trying to use SQLite eventually but this command was written on my mySQL thru WAMP

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for right sytax use near 'auto_increment primary key, class_name VARCHAR(30), assignment_name VARCHAR(30) ' at - line 1

Comment: tossed the sqlite tag on here so people searching those questions can come across this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Android uses SQLite, so your mysql tag is slightly incorrect unless I'm missing something you're doing.

Secondly, you would say

```
CREATE TABLE ASSIGNMENTS(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, class_name TEXT, assignment_name TEXT NOT NULL, due_date TEXT NOT NULL, notes TEXT);
```

"autoincrement" is handled automatically if you set your primary key as an INTEGER type, even though under the covers SQLite uses strings for everything

reference: [SQLite datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

further reference: [INTEGER PRIMARY KEY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)

Even more reference: "If an INSERT statement attempts to insert a NULL value into a rowid or integer primary key column, the system chooses an integer value to use as the rowid automatically. A detailed description of how this is done is provided separately."

Comment: that's definitely a problem i should probably fix but even still if you read my edit i am not doing it thru sql lite

Comment: So somehow you have MySQL on an Android device?!?

Comment: no lol, im testing the command that would be sent thru mySQLite on my mySQL WAMP command prompt thing

Comment: Ah, Pretty sure that won't work. If you have sqlite installed locally you can test by running the "sqlite3" command.

Answer (score 1):

It is `autoincrement`, not `auto_increment`

Comment: You don't need autoincrement in SQLite

Comment: SQLite doesn't need auto increment? i was watching a tutorial on someone doing it though

Comment: See my answer above. When you declare a field as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, it does autoincrementing for you.

Comment: Look to http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html for full explanation of autoincrement.  I would recommend using it if you intend that field to be your index field.